# FInd out if AABB is left/right/below or obove a ray

Tags: collision-detection, raycasting, aabb, raytracing

What algorithms are there to find out in which quadrant of the ray an AABB is given a roll value? My idea was to rotate the cube by the negative rotation of the ray and move it by the negative position and then find out in which part of the coodinate system it is, however this seems to be kind of complicated to be since there are less complicated ray/AABB intersection algorithms and what I am looking for is way less specific. 
It should return an array of bools for all the quadrants, since a box can be in multiple quadrants at a time.

Comment: Is there a particular (higher-level) problem you're trying to solve by doing this, or do you just want to know how to do this for its own sake?

Comment: Its not very simple to explain. I am dividing a camera for rendering into 4 frustums and checking for objects inside these. since i already know which objects are inside the parent frustum i only need to check where these objects are with respect to the "central ray" of the parent frustum

Comment: It sounds like you're wanting to tell which quadrant a box is in when you consider the ray itself as the Z axis of a coordinate system. This requires more than _just_ the ray; you also need another vector to describe the coordinate frame. Otherwise there are an infinite number of "X and Y" axes perpendicular to the "central ray" of your system that subdivide the space into "quadrants." What other information do you have about your camera and the four frustums? That may be sufficient to provide what you need (e.g., if the ray is the camera's look direction and you have the camera's up-vector)

Comment: _Also_, an AABB can straddle these "quadrants..." In fact, it's possible for the AABB to be in all four. What is your desired outcome in that case?

Comment: forgot to add that. ill just make an edit to my question. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your ray `Z` is, as I understand from your comments, the forward vector of your camera, then it plus the up vector `Y` of the camera provide sufficient information to construct the basis vectors for the camera's coordinate system. Assuming a right-handed system, `cross(Z, Y)` will give the sideways-pointing vector `X`.

The vectors of this coordinate frame can be used to define the XZ and YZ planes of the coordinate system. The `Y` vector is the normal, and thus provides the `A`, `B` and `C` components of the XZ plane; `D` is 0, and so on.

These two planes describe your 'quadrants:' any point on the positive half-space of both planes is in quadrant 0. Any point on the positive side of XZ but negative side of YZ is in quadrant 1. And so on:

```
XY sign | YZ sign | quadrant 
   +         +      0
   +         -      1
   -         +      3
   -         -      2
```

With this, you can test each of the box's corners against both planes and determine which quadrant that corner is in. The box itself can be considered to be in all of the quadrants any of its points are in.